# Why is this solution NOT stuck in an endless loop?

Tags: python, arrays

I solved the Minimum Swaps 2 array challenge on HackerRank (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-swaps-2/problem). My solution would timeout with larger arrays, so I went back to refactoring the code. I came upon my new solution, which I realized almost as soon as I submitted it would not work. However, it did.. perfectly, but I'm going mad trying to figure out why. At the very least, why is it not stuck in an endless while loop repeatedly swapping the two array values back and forth? The glaringly obvious aside, let's say it *does* magically break out of the loop, how could it possibly be getting the correct answer under the condition it's using to count the swaps if we're looking for the *minimum* number of swaps? I've added print statements at different points in the code to try to see what's going on and make sense of it myself, but they only add to the confusion. Can someone walk me through the logic of my nonsensical genius? Or is this a fluke?

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the minimumSwaps function below.
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    swaps = 0

    for x in range(0, n - 1):
        while arr[x] != x + 1:
            arr[arr[x] - 1], arr[x] = arr[x], arr[arr[x] - 1]
            swaps += 1

    return swaps


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    n = int(input())

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    res = minimumSwaps(arr)

    fptr.write(str(res) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: Well... at every index `x` either `arr[x]` has already the correct value `x+1` or you swap it so that it is placed at the correct index. You never swap "uselessly" because in just one swap you put the element at the correct position. In other words your algorithm is correct.

Comment: @Bakuriu It isn't necessarily placing the element in the correct position though. For example, in the first run through the for loop, the index is `0`. The number in the array should be `1`, but let's say it's `3`. The program then swaps the `3` with the last number in the array (index `x-1`), which isn't necessarily `1` either. Say it's `5`. Now `3` and `5` get swapped, and we go back to the condition for the while loop, which is still not satisfied, as now we have `5` at index `0` instead of `1`, so it swaps `5` and `3` again.. and again.. etc.. or it should by logic, but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: No it swaps it with `arr[x] -1` not with `x-1`. Keep in mind that you have a conversion between elements and indices. Index to element -> +1, element to index -1. So if `arr[x]` is the element `a` you then swap it with index `a-1` which is the correct index for `a`.

Comment: @Bakuriu You're right about the index flub in my example, but I still don't understand. So instead of swapping with `x-1`, it swaps with `arr[x] - 1`. So, in that case (going along with my example), it would swap our `3` with the element at index `2`, which let's say is `4`. `4` is still not `1`, which would still keep us stuck in the while loop, right?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes it swaps it with `4` **but now `3` is in the correct place!** So now you put `4` at index `3` (which is correct) and you either end up having `1` or an other number... you never end up "looking" at the same number twice inside the `while` loop and since they are finite it follows that at some point you will get that `1`. And after that when you continue on you are going to skip and never touch again all nu,bers that you placed at the correct index. Your error is probably thinking that the `while` loop is going to check again for `3`... that wont ever happen

Comment: @Bakuriu that's exactly what I was thinking. Programming can be so humbling hah. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition on the while checks if the current element is in its correct position:
`while arr[x] != x + 1:`

Each iteration in the loop you move the value of the x position to its correct position which is arr[x]-1. So every iteration in the while corrects the position of one element. See the example below:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> a
[9, 1, 3, 10, 8, 5, 6, 2, 7, 4]
>>> #first iteration
>>> a[a[i]-1], a[i] = a[i], a[a[i] - 1]
>>> a
[7, 1, 3, 10, 8, 5, 6, 2, 9, 4]
>>> #second iteration
>>> a[a[i]-1], a[i] = a[i], a[a[i] - 1]
>>> a
[6, 1, 3, 10, 8, 5, 7, 2, 9, 4]
```

First iteration moves 9 to the 9th position of the array (index 8) and first position becomes 7.
Second iteration moves 7 to the 7th position of the array (index 6) and first position becomes 6.

I hope this is clear enough :)

Answer (score 1):

just if you want to follow your steps

```
                             list  swap_index_1  swap_index_2
0  [7, 9, 6, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 8, 0]           NaN           NaN
1  [1, 9, 6, 4, 2, 5, 7, 3, 8, 0]           0.0           0.0
2  [1, 8, 6, 4, 2, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0]           1.0           7.0
3  [1, 3, 6, 4, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 0]           1.0           2.0
4  [1, 6, 3, 4, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 0]           1.0           5.0
5  [1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]           1.0           4.0
6  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]           1.0           1.0
```

---

```
from random import shuffle
import pandas as pd
steps = []


def log(arr, s1, s2):
    steps.append(dict(list=arr.copy(), swap_index_1=s1, swap_index_2=s2))


n = 10
arr = list(range(n))
shuffle(arr)

swaps = 0

log(arr, None, None)

for x in range(0, n - 1):
        while arr[x] != x + 1:
            arr[arr[x] - 1], arr[x] = arr[x], arr[arr[x] - 1]
            swaps += 1

            log(arr, x, arr[x] - 1)

steps = pd.DataFrame(steps)
print(steps)
```